# Adding New Package To Conda Environment

Tags: python, terminal, pip, anaconda, conda

I am attempting to use the package snnTorch with Conda in Python. My IDE is PyCharm, and I have downloaded snnTorch using "pip3 install snnTorch."

Right now, I believe they're two options.

Option 1 is to attempt to use both pip and Conda. Based on my reading online (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) this is not recommended

Option 2 is to download snnTorch directly into the Conda interpreter. Looking at other questions online, I have seen various "ways" to do this

Among them:

1. Conda install pip (failed)
2. Change working directory to Conda environment and do a pip install (failed)
   [Folders available in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds6GA.png)
3. Type the following in the terminal: python setup.py install /Users/USER_NAME/opt/anaconda3/bin/python and then run the pip install (failed)
4. Activate anaconda and then do pip install snnTorch (failed)

At this time, I still cannot import snnTorch and do not see it listed as an environment. It's very possible that another used had a similar question as myself, and I either missed or misunderstood the answer.

Thank you to anyone who attempts to help!

***UPDATE***
I was never able to get norse to run on Pycharm's IDE directly; however, I could run it if I was using a virtual environment on my terminal. Moreover, I found that Google Colab allowed me to run the norse library directly.

Comment: Sounds like **Option 2** is trying to reinvent **Option 1**. The doc in **Option 1** provides clear directions on how to safely mix Pip and Conda. Follow them.

Answer (score 0):

If the package is not available through conda, then you should use pip

```sh
conda activate
python -m pip install snnTorch
```

Should do it.

This makes sure that the version of pip you are using is the one inside the conda envinronment you wish to install it into.

Comment: Thank you HPringles. I copied and pasted the above code and the download "worked." However, I still do not see snnTorch listed as an option among the anaconda libraries and "import snnTorch" still does not work in the code itself

Answer (score 0):

The package has not been built into a conda binary yet.  You can install it using PIP, but I would still recommend using conda to install the dependencies first if you are using a conda environment.

```
conda create -n snn pytorch torchvision pandas h5py matplotlib -c defaults -c pytorch -y
conda activate snn
pip install snnTorch
```

This will create a new conda environment with the majority of the required packages using conda.  Then uses pip to install snnTorch

Answer (score 0):

As per [the referenced document](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment), when Pip must be used, then best practice is to create a new environment and use a YAML file.

**snntorch.yaml**

```yaml
name: snntorch
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  ## core 
  - python=3.9      # set preferred version
  - ipykernel       # enables using env as Jupyter kernel

  ## snnTorch Conda dependencies
  - pytorch >=1.2.0
  - torchvision >=0.9.1
  - numpy >=1.17
  - h5py >=3.0.0
  - tqdm
  - pandas
  - matplotlib

  ## PyPI
  - pip
  - pip:
    # - celluloid   # this will automatically resolve
    - snntorch
```

**BASH session**

```bash
conda env create -n snntorch -f -snntorch.yaml
```

If you need additional packages, edit the YAML and recreate the environment.